# Is there a way to access an Html element which is a file and then use the file in Suitescript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Im a new to SuiteScript and im trying to integrate Google Drive with Netsuite to upload file to drive and then attach the file to transaction.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */

define(['N/ui/serverWidget', "N/file" , "N/redirect" , "N/url" , "N/currentRecord" , "N/record" ],
     (serverWidget, file , redirect , url  , currentRecord  , record) => { 




        function onRequest(context) {
            var fileObj;
            var recIDs = context.request.parameters.recId; 
            log.debug("record id " , recIDs)
            
 


            fileObj = context.request.files.custpage_file;
            fileObj.folder = -10; //replace with own folder ID
                var fileid = fileObj.save();

              
              

    var html =  `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Drive API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Drive API Quickstart</p>
      
    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
    

    <button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>
    

    <form id = "form">
      <label for = "file"> Select File to Upload:</label>
      <input type  = "file" id= "file">
      <input type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Upload File">
      
    
    </form>    

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* exported gapiLoaded */
    /* exported gisLoaded */
    /* exported handleAuthClick */
    /* exported handleSignoutClick */

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = '45285368591-61vroblu2lkmvcg0sp1teuv56kkdvt8v.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCIzre52evS8bJjs91HTRj_4yhcTkWBcgc';

    // TODO(developer): Replace with your own project number from console.developers.google.com.
    const APP_ID = '45285368591';

    // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
    const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest';

  

    let tokenClient;
    let gapiInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;

    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
    gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function initializeGapiClient() {
    await gapi.client.init({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
    });
    gapiInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    scope: SCOPES,
    callback: '', // defined later
    });
    gisInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
     */
    function maybeEnableButtons() {
    if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('file').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('submit').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
    tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
    if (resp.error !== undefined) {
    throw (resp);
    }
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
    document.getElementById('file').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('submit').style.visibility = 'visible';


    };

    if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
    // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
    // when establishing a new session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
    } else {
    // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
    }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
    var token = gapi.client.getToken();
    if (token !== null) {
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
    gapi.client.setToken('');
    document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
    document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    }
    }



    form.onsubmit = uploadFile

    function uploadFile(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      
      
      let length = file.files.length
      console.log(length.type)
      
      Array.from(file.files).forEach((f)=> {
        console.log(f)
        
      let data = new FormData()

      let metaData = {
        name:f.name,
        mimetype:f.type,
        //parents:['googledrivefolderid']
      }

      data.append('metadata' , new Blob([JSON.stringify(metaData)],{
        type:"application/json"
        } ))
        data.append('file' , f)

        var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    

        

        
        // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.
        fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fileds=id", {
          method: 'POST',
          headers : new Headers({Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken}),
          body:data 
        })
        .then((res) =>{
          return res.json()
        })
        .then((val) => {
          length = length - 1
          console.log(val)
          if(length == 0){
            alert("File Has been Uploaded")
            file.value = ""
          }
        })
        .catch((err)=>  {
          console.log(err );
        })
        })

      }
      
    
  
    
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
    </body>
    </html>`
      




       context.response.write(html);

     log.debug("file" , fileObj)
      /** Attach PDF File in the Sales Order Transaction **/            

            
        
        
        }


               
}

return {
onRequest: onRequest
};

});
```

Im able to upload the file but i cant access the file element insides my HTML. is there a way to do that?.

i tried to do the opposite which is upload the file from netsuite but again is not accessible in the HTML form.

Comment: Hi - Is there any reason why you are using raw HTML code over simply building your widgets using the "N/ui/serverWidget" module"? Analysing code and offering advice becomes increasingly difficult when different practices are used for Suitelet scripts.